# Is it possible to make BitmapFactory.decodeFile() respect EXIF?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, exif

In my tests, a `Bitmap` created by `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` doesn't respect EXIF header.

For example, with portrait images taken by a devices that doesn't rotate actual pixel data depending on camera orientation but rather stores it in EXIF header, when I'm calling `Bitmap.getWidth()` and `Bitmap.getHeight()`, they return incorrect values (height for width and vice versa).

Is there a way to make  `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` respect EXIF and produce a correct `Bitmap`?

If not, what is the recommended pattern to handle this issue?

Without an advice from experienced Android devs, the only way I see is to pre-process taken images (load, rotate according to EXIF, and save). But apart from the huge processing overhead, this might cause `OutOfMemoryException`s for large camera resolutions (in cases when you can't reduce the quality by using `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` to load downscaled images).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to make BitmapFactory.decodeFile() respect EXIF and produce a correct Bitmap?

No, sorry.

> what is the recommended pattern to handle this issue?

Use the support library's `ExifInterface` to determine the desired orientation. Then, depending upon your use of the `Bitmap`, either rotate the view (e.g., `ImageView`) or rotate the `Bitmap`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Camera/EXIFRotater) illustrates both approaches, though I use a separate set of EXIF code, as some things that I use in that sample are not supported by the support library's `ExifInterface`.

Comment: `Use the support library's ExifInterface`: In your sample you use `it.sephiroth.android.library.exif2` library. Does it have any advantages compared to `android.media.ExifInterface` for this specific case? If this is due that some implementations of stock `ExifInterface` were buggy, does it still applies to APIs >= 14? Or for these newer APIs `android.media.ExifInterface` should be fine?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: I wanted to write out the modified bitmap. That requires removing the thumbnail and updating the EXIF orientation tag. [The support library's `ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html) does not offer the `removeCompressedThumbnail()` method. If you are not saving the modified bitmap, this should not be an issue.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: Prior to Android 7.0, the platform's `ExifInterface` [has a significant security flaw](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/08/dealing-exifinterface-security-flaw.html). [Use the support library's `ExifInterface`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/12/15/about-support-exifinterface.html) or another Java-based EXIF implementation (such as the code that I have in that sample).

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with Glide now.  See the "Background Threads" section here:

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html

Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(new File(fileName)).skipMemoryCache(true).submit().get();

Glide takes into consideration EXIF.  You'll need to load it on a background thread.  I was using Glide 4.9.0

Answer (score 3):

As it turned out, resolving the initial issue turned into the set of new ones. Here is the complete tutorial for further readers.

First of all, as [@CommonsWare pointed in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45552197/3345644), we have to handle orientation manually using EXIF orientation tag. To avoid buggy/security flawed `android.media.ExifInterface` as well as 3rd party dependencies, the best option seems to be a new `com.android.support:exifinterface` library, which we add to `build.gradle` as:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.0'
}
```

However for me, it led to a Gradle sync error caused by that this specific newest version of the library is not found in Google repositories, though this version is the latest according to the [Support Library Packages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#exif) page.

After an hour of trials, I figured out that `jcenter()` repository is not enough and Gradle sync was fixed by adding Google Maven repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, now we're able to use `android.support.media.ExifInterface`.

The next disappointment was that width and height stored in EXIF tags also do not respect orientation, i.e. for images taken in portrait mode you get the same width and height that are returned by a `Bitmap` created with `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`. So the only way is to manually look at the EXIF `ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION` tag and if it says that image is rotated 90 or 270 degree - swap width and height:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(fileNameFull);
orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

BitmapFactory.Options optsForBounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
optsForBounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, optsForBounds);

int width = optsForBounds.outWidth, height = optsForBounds.outHeight;
if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 || orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270)
{
    int temp = width;
    //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
    width = height;
    height = temp;
}
```

I'm not sure if this approach and code covers 100% of cases, so if you encounter any issues across various devices/image sources - feel free to comment.

In general, dealing with EXIF doesn't seem to be a pleasant experience. Implementations of the EXIF standard even from big companies seem to treat nuances very differently. See extensive analysis [here](https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap = getThumb(file, dimensionPixelSize);

public Bitmap getThumb(String file, float thumbSize) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, OutOfMemoryError {

    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file);
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    mOptions.inSampleSize = getSample(file, thumbSize);
    mOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, mOptions);

    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 || orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        return rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);
    } else {
        return bitmap;
    }

}

public int getSample(String file, float thumbSize) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, OutOfMemoryError {
    mOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, mOptions);
    int size = Math.round(Math.max(mOptions.outWidth, mOptions.outHeight) / thumbSize);
    if (size % 2 != 0) {
        size--;
    }
    return size;
}

public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
     matrix.postRotate(angle);
     return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```