# Why image rotates after downsampling?

Tags: android, android-image

I am downsampling image with following code

```
  private static Bitmap downsample(String path) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = 1;
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    bitmapOptions.inDensity = 1;
    bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = 1;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    int reqWidth = 800, reqHeight = 800;
    final int newWidth = imageWidth / bitmapOptions.inSampleSize, newHeight =
        imageHeight / bitmapOptions.inSampleSize;
    if (newWidth > reqWidth || newHeight > reqHeight) {
      if (newWidth * reqHeight > newHeight * reqWidth) {
        // prefer width, as the width ratio is larger
        bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = reqWidth;
        bitmapOptions.inDensity = newWidth;
      } else {
        // prefer height
        bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = reqHeight;
        bitmapOptions.inDensity = newHeight;
      }
    }
    final Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bitmapOptions);
    scaledBitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
    return scaledBitmap;
  }
```

and load with glide

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
          .load(MainActivity.mProfile.getImg())
          .override(avatarSize, avatarSize)
          .centerCrop()
          .error(R.drawable.placeholder_photo)
          .into(imAvatar);
```

However resulting bitmap i rotated 90 degree if original height bigger then width.

Comment: How **exactly** have you determined that "resulting bitmap i rotated 90 degree"? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45552108/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare i put side by side to image views. at left i load original image and to the right i loaded downsabled image. The righ image is rotated.

Comment: How **exactly** did you "put side by side to image views"? For example, did you use an image-loading library that honors EXIF tags? If so, then your original image probably had an EXIF `orientation` tag. Your downsampled image does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare the problem was really in handling exif tag